# Start Hadoop 2.7.1 with Windows 10 and command lines : ERROR the system cannot find the file hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, cmd, hadoop2

I'm trying to install and start Hadoop 2.7.1 on my computer (windows 10) with command lines and I have followed steps from different websites for that. I have configurated systems variables and Hadoop (edit some files in etc folder : `Hadoop-env.cmd`, `core-site.xml`, `mapred-site.xml`, `yarn-site.xml`, `hdfs-site.xml`) and download a new bin folder. I'm currently trying to start Hadoop and I have executed the command `hdfs namenode -format` successfully.

However, when pointing in command prompt to **sbin** folder and trying to execute start-dfs.cmd I have an error message telling : `The system cannot find the file hadoop`. Anyone has any idea what I should do or have done wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Set the Hadoop home and path variable in environment variable path

[image: Hadoop_home]

Comment: Please find the attachments for more clear information

Answer (score 0):

change the file name from hadoop to hadoop.cmd in bin/hadoop.cmd

and run start-all in cmd and check if it is working or not.

and check java_home path in environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Old but for others starting out, this is how I fixed this problem. I will assume you have followed: 

https://github.com/MuhammadBilalYar/Hadoop-On-Window/wiki/Step-by-step-Hadoop-2.8.0-installation-on-Window-10 

And are having troubles.

Open start-all.cmd in 'C:\hadoop-2.8.0\sbin' in a text editor like notepad++

Replace line 24 with set 'HADOOP_BIN_PATH=C:\hadoop-2.8.0\bin'

In this file note the calls to 'hadoop-config .cmd' , 'start-dfs .cmd' , 'start-yarn.cmd'. Open these in a text editor.

Replace the hadoop path as per step 2 . Set HADOOP_BIN_PATH=C:\hadoop-2.8.0\bin

Save files and re-run your start-all cmd

Hope this helps. `